# ModemManager get two wwan connections

Tags: linux, iot, mmcli

i have got modem with double sim slot to insert two different sim cards.

mmcli output:

```
  -----------------------------------
  3GPP EPS |    ue mode of operation: csps-2
           |     initial bearer path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/2
           |  initial bearer ip type: ipv4v6
  -----------------------------------
  SIM      |        primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/3
           |          sim slot paths: slot 1: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/2
           |                          slot 2: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/3 (active)
  -----------------------------------
  Bearer   |                   paths: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/3
```

Is there a possibility to get two activated wwan's from this sim cards? I can switch between them but i want to try to get two of them at once.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be unworkable. Producer not provide dual sim support for model of modem which i have.
Additional information in this link [Quectel Specification](https://www.quectel.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Quectel_RM520N-Series_5G_Specification_V1.1.pdf). There are no information about 'dual sim' unlike these [SCx modems](https://www.quectel.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Quectel-Product-Brochure-EN-v6.8.pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).